# GooglePlayServices Ads (AdMob) don't show on HTC Desire

Tags: android, google-play, admob, apk, google-play-services

I've put GooglePlayService Ads to my app and ran on my tablet. It worked properly. But when do I run it on HTC Desire - API 10 - 2.3.3 - I it doesn't show at all.

Do the ads show only when the app is in .apk file and put to GooglePlay or is it another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ads shown you have to add your device like the test one, for example:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)       // Emulator
    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4") // your phone code
    .build();
```

I'd like to remark that you have to find your phone code in logcat window. That would be working even if your are working without .apk, also don't forget that for different devices you will have to add different phone codes.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. So if I dont addtestdevice it there and put it on Play Store, the ad will show to everyone?

Comment: Yes, but you must be sure also that you put right AdUnitId in your AdView element.

Comment: And one more thing: Ive put yesterday code of my tablet there and nothing happened. when i erased it, it appeared. How comes that the ads show on tablet even though it isnt in test-mode?

Comment: Not sure what are you about right now, but sometimes google caches data on server and some time it still appear even if you close access in google console

Comment: So I've added both device IDs there and emulator and if i do so, it disappears even from my tablet. When do I delete it, it appears there - but on HTC still nothing. It isnt so important for me right now but I just want to be sure, that if i put somethin on the GooglePlay and someone with HTC Desire downloads it, the ad will be showing him. Is that true? Thanks for your help again

Comment: That's it, one more remark about google policy: there must be no more than 1 ad per page.